# flutter error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, mobile

who can help me with this error that I have been trying to solve for almost 2 days and I have not been able to.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0lx1.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYpHu.png)

I have done several things, removed flutter and reinstalled it, flutter clean and flutter pub get and tried to update all the dependencies but nothing has worked, what do you think it could be? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you give us more info about the whole error log?  error message at start.

Comment: These are the first error lines https://ibb.co/zHHNdq9

Comment: The errors says it all. It's not able to find `VelocityTracker`.. BTW What's your flutter version? Please also include your pubspec file

Comment: if I use the flutter --version command it tells me 3.0.5, I will attach my pubspec file

part 1: https://ibb.co/D4TGqgf
part 2: https://ibb.co/dmYGZmQ

Comment: part 3: https://ibb.co/kXWdQXP

Comment: Unfortunately, your app is inside a dependency hell and it's quite hard to get out of this. Some packages are quite old and do not even support the new flutter version. The only way to handle these kinds of situations is to get rid of packages that are outdated and use alternative packages.

Answer (score 0):

Add null aware operator(?.) before `instance` like this,

Replace,

```
SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallBack
```

To,

```
SchedulerBinding?.instance!.addPostFrameCallBack
```

Comment: The errors are coming from packages and these are out of control of the user

Comment: I know its temporary solution to edit package files.

Comment: I made all the changes but now I get the 
Error: Couldn't find constructor 'VelocityTracker'.
  VelocityTracker _vt = new VelocityTracker();
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


and I still get the error of: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

Comment: Because package is not updated..
For more info : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104396

Comment: Use older version of flutter or remove that package is only solution for now.

Comment: That is, should I use the command 'flutter downgrade <version>'?

Comment: Yes, you can use that command.

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of **sliding_up_panel** and go to
this location and delete the older versions of **sliding_up_panel**

OR

you can just directly delete **sliding_up_panel** from given location if you are not using the package in current project

```
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\
```